# The derivative of $f(x^2)$

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I wanted to ask something.
Let there be a function $f(x^2)$, then the first derivative is $2 x f'(x^2)$ or only $f'(x^2)$ ? 
Its just something I want to be sure about cause it's some kinda confusing me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: $2xf'(x^{2})$. It comes from the chain rule.

Comment: You could try some examples. What is the first derivative of $(x^2)^3({}=x^6)$? The first interpretation says $2x\cdot 3(x^2)^2$, while the other says $3(x^2)^2$. Which is correct?

Comment: $\bigl(f(\square)\bigr)'=f'(\square)\cdot\square'$.  Now let $\square=x^2$.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider the function $f(x^2)$ as a function of $x$, so you should look at it as $h(x)=f(x^2)$, which you can see as $h(x)=f(g(x))=f\circ g(x)$ where $g(x)=x^2$. Thus $h'(x)=(f(x^2))'=g'(x)f'(g(x))=2xf'(x^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^{2}$. Then, $f(x^{2})=f(u)$. You want to differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$. By the chain rule
$$
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=f'(u)\cdot(2x)=2x\cdot f'(x^{2}).
$$